# Navigation with Arguments with Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I've been troubleshooting this issue for couple of days now about navigating with args in jetpack compose. I feel like I'm missing something simple, really simple that I can't figure out somehow.
I tried making sure I'm coding it correctly but to no avail I still get the error.

So the error:
Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/second_screen/Item Six } cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(0x0) startDestination={Destination(0x442b361f) route=home_screen}

I feel like I'm done everything correct but still cant get through this error. Or there is something simple that I'm missing.

My NavHost:

```
interface NavigationDestination{
    val route: String
}

@Composable
fun MainNavHost(
){
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = HomeScreenNavigation.route,
    ){
        composable(HomeScreenNavigation.route){
            HomeScreen(onItemClick = {nameString->
                    navController.navigate("${SecondNavigationDestination.route}/${nameString}")
                        {
                            launchSingleTop = true
                        }
            })
        }
        composable(
            route = SecondNavigationDestination.routeWithArg,
            arguments = listOf(navArgument(SecondNavigationDestination.nameArg)
            {type = NavType.StringType})
        ){
            SecondScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

My Screens

First Screen:

```
object HomeScreenNavigation: NavigationDestination{
    override val route = "home_screen"
}

@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onItemClick: (String) -> Unit
){
    ItemList(
        itemList = LocalData.itemList,
        onItemClick = onItemClick
    )
}

@Composable
fun ItemList(
    itemList: List<ItemModel>,
    onItemClick: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    LazyColumn(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(9.dp)
    ){
        items(
            items = itemList,
            key = {it.id}
        ){
            Item(
                item = it,
                onItemClick = onItemClick
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Item(
    item: ItemModel,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onItemClick: (String) -> Unit
){
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(9.dp)
            .clickable { onItemClick(item.name) },
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top
    ){
    Text(
        text = item.name
    )
    }
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Second Screen:

```
object SecondNavigationDestination: NavigationDestination{
    override val route = "second_screen"
    const val nameArg = "nameArg"
    val routeWithArg = "${route}/$nameArg"
}

@Composable
fun SecondScreen(
){
    val viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()
    Box(
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ){
        Text(
            viewModel.id
        )
    }
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel(
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
): ViewModel(){
    val id: String = savedStateHandle[SecondNavigationDestination.nameArg] ?: "empty"
}
```

Comment: you should put your argument inside a {} in the ```const val nameArg = "{nameArg}"```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```kotlin
val routeWithArg = "${route}/$nameArg"
```

to this

```kotlin
val routeWithArg = "${route}/{$nameArg}"
```

For more info: [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-with-args)

Comment: I'm actually playing around with it just now and about to post the answer. I knew this is something really simple that I'm missing. Yes you are right the answer is the same as your comment. at first it was "${route}/${nameArg}. Thanks @Javlon

Comment: 2 days I get bugged by this haha curly braces beginner syndrome my mind always assume ${nameArg}, this is brain assumption error. but I also blame the code design. when you append in kotlin it was always dollar sign with curly braces, until you learned that appending in navigation arguments is different

Comment: Thank you sir.Its worked to my project.I used to 2 arguments.I  was transporting one item with argument and other argument transport with saved state.I have  excetion to IllegalArgumentException.Its solved thanks
   route = "${Screen.PokemonDetailScreen.route}/{$DOMINANT_COLOR}/{$POKEMON_NAME}",

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to carry data with more than one argument, your definition should be like this.

route ="${Screen.PokemonDetailScreen.route}/{$DOMINANT_COLOR}/{$POKEMON_NAME}",